# Speech reorganization helper class

Tags: java, android

I am working on a speech reorganization project. I have a util class that consists of three methods: check if a microphone exists, check microphone availability, and check text-to-speech availability. Can anyone review my code?

```
public class MediaUtil {

    //returns whether a microphone exists
    public boolean getMicrophoneExists(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        return packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE);
    }

    //returns whether the microphone is available
    public static boolean getMicrophoneAvailable(Context context) {
        MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setOutputFile(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "MediaUtil#micAvailTestFile").getAbsolutePath());
        boolean available = true;
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        }
        catch (IOException exception) {
            available = false;
        }
        recorder.release();
        return available;
    }

    //returns whether text to speech is available
    public static boolean getTTSAvailable(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        List<ResolveInfo> speechActivities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(speechIntent, 0);
        if (speechActivities.size() != 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Returning boolean**

  A pattern

  ```
      if (condition) return true;
      return false
  ```

  is to be avoided.

  ```
      return condition;
  ```

  achieves the same in a much more transparent manner. In your case,

  ```
      return speechActivities.size() != 0;
  ```
- **Testing vs acquisition**

  Consider the situation: by the time you call `getMicrophoneAvailable` it might be available, but later on when your app actually needs it, it's been successfully claimed by some other app.

  It means there is no point to *test* for availability. Acquire it as you need it:

  ```
      public static MediaRecorder getMicrophone(Context context) {
          ....
          try {
              recorder.prepare();
          } catch (IOException exception) {
              return null;
          }
          return recorder;
      }
  ```

Comment: Also, using isEmpty is more natural than checking if size is 0